# How does Zookeeper set its zNode permissions with SASL authentication?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, ambari

Let's imagine you are in a Kerberized Ambari environment. Zookeeper is set to SASL with only read permissions for no autheticated users.

When you start your kafka broker, it will autheticate against zookeeper as «kafka» and be able to create the znode. Looking at the zookeeper acls, «kafka» will be granted cdrwa (all) permissions on the zode, automatically.

My question is, does zookeeper have this kind of behaviour because it is in an ambari enviroment which does not restrict users in its jaas config Client section, automatically granting zookeeper acl permissions on new zNodes?

Sorry for the format, im with the mobile at 1.53 am...zzz.Zz

Comment: autheNticate.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `zookeeer.set.acl` set to `true`, than Kafka will set secured ACLs on any new created zkNode if it matches one of `ZkUtils.SecureZkRootPaths` parents (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0.1/core/src/main/scala/kafka/utils/ZkUtils.scala#L114))

Comment: Thanks for your time Mariusz. Appreciated!